# Using Python script to find duplicate database records is too slow

Tags: python, django, duplicates, fuzzy-comparison

We have a database with 100.000 artists. However, some artists are duplicates. We want to run the script below to compare every artist to all other artists and get a list of duplicates.

```
artistquery = Artist.objects.filter(mainartist__rank__pos__lt=999, created_at__gt=latestcheckdate).order_by('name').distinct()

from difflib import SequenceMatcher

for artist in artistquery:
    checkedartistlist.append(artist.id)
    ref_artistquery = Artist.objects.all().exclude(id__in=checkedartistlist)

    for ref_artist in ref_artistquery:
        similarity = SequenceMatcher(None, artist.name, ref_artist.name).ratio()
        if similarity > 0.90:

            SimilarArtist.objects.get_or_create(artist1=artist, artist2=ref_artist)
```

Unfortunately, this results in 10 billion comparisons. Is there a way to accomplish it more efficiently and quickly?

Comment: do the distinct before ordering, or maybe don't bother ordering at all

Comment: aside from the optimization of the algo, looks like a decente use case for python multithreading. Dig around this topic: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multithreading-python-set-1/

Comment: If your database is PostgreSQL you can try to filter using `trigram_similar` and remove the loops: [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/postgres/lookups/](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/postgres/lookups/)